# Adding accordion menu into tabs: merging JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, accordion

I am trying to merge ACCORDION menu into my existing TABS menu. Well, I have a working example of Accordion menu withing Tabs, taken from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DJXTV/).

Honestly speaking, I failed to fully understand how it works; whereas html structure is clear, JS is not. I am using Dreamweaver, which can generate tabs and accordion from scratch, using jQuery UI library. For tabs DW generates:

```
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.tabs.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.tabs.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and for ACCORDION, DW generates a similar set:

```
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.accordion.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.accordion.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The question is: how to merge ACCORDION JS into my existing TABS JS. Is there a single JS file covering the entire functionality.

Pardon if this question sounds bizarre and unprofessional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto https://jqueryui.com/download/

Select which widgets you want to use and you will get 1 custom file having these two widgets.

Comment: In downloaded archive - development-bundle? Do I need it?

Comment: Click [here](https://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.4&components=1100000001000000001000000000000000) and download. This is minimum number of components you can have to use accordion and tabs. In the download file you will have a minified file which you can use.